# ADO.NET Error when executing SQL statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I try to crate a login and sign up. I have DB_Connectivity and queries classes when I try to logon or submit in signup form I have got an error

> Error you have an error in your sql syntax check the manual that corresponds to your Mysql server version for the right syntax to use near [User Name], Password From signup Where [User Name] = username1 ......... at line1

Same happens in signup Exception throws " Unknown Error ............. at line1"

This is `DB_Connectivity` class

```
 class DB_Connectivity
    {
        private string myconnection;
        private string server;
        private string database;
        private string uid;
        private string password;
        public MySqlConnection conn;

        public DB_Connectivity()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        public void Initialize()
        {
            server = "localhost";
            database = "my_project_data";
            uid = "root";
            password = "";

            myconnection = "SERVER = " + server + ";" + "DATABASE =" + database + ";" + "UID =" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD =" + password + ";";

            conn = new MySqlConnection(myconnection);
        }

        public void openConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
            }

            catch (MySqlException ms)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error Occured " + ms.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(" Error Please Contact Administrator " +ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public void closeConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(" Unexpected Error " +ex.Message);
            }

        }
    }
```

This is query class

```
class Queries :DB_Connectivity
{
        private MySqlCommand cmd;
        private MySqlDataReader datar;
        private string sql_query;

        public void insertIntoSignup(string firstname, string lastname, string address, string phone, string email, string username, string password )
        {
            try
            {
                sql_query = "Insert Into my_project_data.signup([First Name],[Last Name],Address,Phone,E-Mail,[User Name],Password) Values('"+firstname+"','"+lastname+"','"+address+"','"+phone+"','"+email+"','"+username+"','"+password+"')";

                openConnection();
                cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql_query, conn);
                datar = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                closeConnection();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Ooooops Error "  +ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public void userlogchech(string username1, string password1)
        {
            try
            {
                sql_query = "Select [User Name],Password From signup Where [User Name] = username1 AND Password = password1";

                openConnection();
                cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql_query, conn);
                datar = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (datar.Read())
                {
                    if (username1 != "")
                    {
                        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("User Name Alredy Exists", "Error");
                    }
                    else if (password1 != "")
                    {
                        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Password Already Exists");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        datar.Close();
                        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Welcome to German Moters");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Try Again Later");
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(" Unknown Error " +ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Log on Button

```
 private void Log_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (User_Name_txt.Text != "" && mask_Password_txt.Text != "")
            {
                Classes.Queries qua = new Classes.Queries();
                qua.userlogchech(User_Name_txt.Text, mask_Password_txt.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Both User Name And Password");
            }
        }
```

Submit button in signup form

```
  private void Submit_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (UserName_txt.Text != "" && mask1_password_txt.Text != "" && FName_txt.Text != "" && LName_txt.Text != "" && Address_txt.Text != "" && Phone_txt.Text != "" && Email_txt.Text != "")
            {

                Classes.Queries qu = new Classes.Queries();
                qu.insertIntoSignup(FName_txt.Text,LName_txt.Text,Address_txt.Text,Phone_txt.Text,Email_txt.Text, UserName_txt.Text,mask1_password_txt.Text );
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("All Fields Must Be Filled ", "Error" ,MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You lack the "minimal" part. We shouldn't have to dig through all your code, or guess which line is throwing the exception. Only provide the minimum amount of code needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please choose a better title, `I am a C# beginner so please help me to solve this` is not representative of the contents of the question.

Comment: In your `userlogchech` method you have a space in `User Name` column names do not have spaces

Comment: You also need to make an effort to narrow down the problem. Regurgitating all of the code when the problem is only with a couple lines makes your question very difficult to answer. English may not be your first language, so not a big deal but its Q U **E** R Y, not Q U **A** R Y.

Comment: Sorry for my stupid mistakes I will not do this again  and also English is not my first language so sorry about spelling mistakes too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a field with a space, `User Name`, change this to `[User Name]` with the square brackets, and do the dame for *First Name*, *Last Name* etc.  You should try and avoid using spaces in the field names, replace them with *UserName*, *FirstName* etc.

Comment: I try your ( [User Name] ) way but still it gave me the same error

Comment: @Hasiya55, you also changed the other fields with a *space*?

Comment: yes [User Name] , [First Name] and [Last Name] but still it gives me error (I also edited the code in question using your method)

Comment: Is `Phone` a string value in the DB? have you tried to run the exact same query direct on the database?

Comment: No phone Is an Integer value in database **********                            when I run this code as Insert Into my_project_data.signup Values('"+firstname+"','"+lastname+"','"+address+"','"+phone+"','"+email+"','"+username+"','"+password+"')" it is working but values are in the wrong columns (firstname is in username, lastname is in password ....like that)

Comment: You are wrapping `phone` is single quotes, suggesting non-numeric.  When you use `INSERT`, it's best practice to include the fields you're inserting into...i.e. `INSERT INTO (field1, field2) VALUES (Val1, Val2)` etc

Comment: I create new table as you said(without spaces in names) "Insert Into my_project_data.signup(UserName,Password,FirstName,LastName,Address,Phone,Email) Values('"+username+"','"+password+"','"+firstname+"','"+lastname+"','"+address+"','"+phone+"','"+email+"')";  and now its working fine thank you 4 all advices